# How to vectorize (i.e. remove the for loop from) this piece of code which generates a discrete PDF from a time series

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am writing a function which performs the following task:

It takes a time series of N points X[i], and produces out a PDF p:[X_min,X_max]->R, which is piecewise constant on each of M equally spaced 'bins' [X_min, X_min + delta], [X_min + delta, X_min + 2*delta], ..., [X_max - delta, X_max] (so delta=(X_max-X_min)/M), and which indicates how long the time series spends in each bin. More precisely, it produces an array P with P[i] = #{k : X[k]\in[X_min + i* delta, X_min + i*(delta+1)]} / N.

Thus my function takes as input a numpy array X = [X[0], ..., X[N-1]] of length N, together with a number M specifying how many bins, and produces as output a numpy array P = [P[0], ..., P[M-1]] of length M and size 1.

So far my code relies on a for loop, and looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
def func(X,M):
    N=np.size(X)
    P = np.array([0]*M)
    X_min = np.amin(X)
    X_max = np.amax(X)
    delta = (X_max - X_min)/M
    for k in np.arange(N):
        j = int( (X[k]-X_min) // delta )
        P[j] += 1
    P = P / N
    return P
```

I need to use this function many times in a computation with large arrays, and I have been advised by a friend that I may be able to speed things up drastically by vectorizing, rather than using a for loop. I can see how to vectorise the first part of the loop, by defining a 'counting vector' `J = ((X-X_min) // delta).astype(int)` of length N which indicates which bin each element of the time series belongs to, but then I am not sure how to implement the second part (i.e. construct a vector P from J, so that P[i] counts the number of occurences of the integer i in J) without falling back on a for loop.

Does anyone have any ideas for ways to efficiently code what I want, either using existing vectorized functions or otherwise?

Many thanks! A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replace the loop portion with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
P = np.bincount(((X-X_min) // delta).astype(int), minlength=M)
```

Comment: Thank-you this is exactly the function I need!